# Displaying the csv file content in a view

Tags: views, feeds, importing-exporting

We imported the content of the excel sheet into csv and generated a view using feeds importer(Feeds module). But we want show the csv file content onto a slidershow. How to display them on a revolution slider.

Answer (score 0):

Change the said view's display format to "Slideshow". You also will have a whole bunch of settings to customize your slideshow.

PS: You only get this format when you install the [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module